# Which is the correct tense: "earth was/is round"?

Tags: tenses, indirect-speech, backshifting

Maybe it's very simple but I'm wondering which one is correct. Google search has showed me both forms are used.

- "He said the earth *was* round."
- "He said the earth *is* round."

Comment: The earth was round—and it still is. (Both are correct.)

Comment: Neither: it is an [oblate spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_the_Earth#Ellipsoid_of_revolution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the sentences are correct. It depends on what context and which tense you are using it. For example:

**Past tense**:

> Aristotle was the first person who described the shape of the Earth.
>   He said the Earth was round but no one believed him then. However,
>   today it's a known fact.

**Present tense**:

> I asked my professor, "What is the shape of the Earth?" He said, "The
>   Earth is round."

Comment: Please provide examples of different contexts where each tense could be applicable. This is not for me but for the OP.

Comment: PAST TENSE- Aristotle was the first person who described the shape of the earth. He said the earth was round but no one believed him then. However, today its a known fact.

Comment: Present tense- I asked my professor- "What is the shape of the Earth". "He said the earth is round"

Comment: Hi Shirin, welcome to EL&U. You might not have understood that Mari-Lou was suggesting you [edit] your *answer* rather than provide the detail as comments. I'll edit your answer for you, but for future reference, we expect this level of detail to be included *in the answer*. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. I look forward to your future contributions :-)

Comment: Oh sorry! My bad. Thanks for informing me. I will keep this in mind the next time